# Using CSS in jQuery Syntax error property name include dash characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to change style of an image, its OK untill this:

> There is a dash in 'justify-content' property 's name

```
$('#pic-upload').css({
    display: "flex",             //This is OK
    justify-content: "center",   // This is an error (have a dash in 'justify-content' property 's name)
    align-items: "center"        // And ofcourse this is also a more error
});
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the property name in quotes:

```
$('#pic-upload').css({
    "justify-content": "center",   
    "align-items": "center"        
});
```

Or you can use camel-casing:

```
$('#pic-upload').css({
    justifyContent: "center",   
    alignItems: "center"        
});
```

Reference:
https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Answer (score 1):

You can code using camelCase syntax:

```
$('#pic-upload').css({
    display: "flex",             
    justifyContent: "center",  
    alignItems: "center"       
});
```